# Can We use RADIUS server along with access proxy in Zero Trust Architecture?

Tags: networking, proxy, architecture, radius, access-point

Can We use RADIUS server along with access proxy in Zero Trust Architecture ?
is there a difference in radius server and access proxy ?
Can we both use them in the same architecture ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use both.
RADIUS is a protocol for authentication and authorization. It is used to authenticate users and devices.
Access proxy is a proxy that is used to control access to resources. It is used to authorize users and devices.